# Interface (or class?) which can read a member variable, but requires a setter to set

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure if I need a class or an interface, but I'd like to create an object which has a member variable which can be easily accessed as a usual variable, like:

```
interface LineRange {
    begin: number;
    end: number;
}
```

BUT setting the value would require a separate setter() function, making it harder to accidentally modify.

Eg.:

```
// Just initialize the class, interface or anything I need
let item: LineRange;

// able to access it like:
const foo: number = item.begin;

// deny to modify:
const bar: number = item.begin++;

// ability to set but only if I use the specific setter:
item.setBegin(42);
```

Is this possible? How?

*Ps.: I would not like to introduce a getBegin() function just for reading a simple member*

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#readonly-properties

Comment: @JBNizet How would I set a readonly parameter after it's created?

Comment: It would be declared readonly in your interface. Not in your implementation, where it could be read-write, or accessed by a getter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `begin` an accessor property with just a getter, then have a method for `setBegin`:

```
class LineRange {
    constructor(
        private _begin: number,
        private _end: number
    ) {
    }
    get begin(): number {
        return this._begin;
    }
    setBegin(begin: number): void {
        this._begin = begin;
    }
    get end(): number {
        return this._end;
    }
    setEnd(end: number): void {
        this._end = end;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
const lr = new LineRange(0, 0);
console.log(lr.begin); // 0
// lr.begin = 42; <== Would be an error
lr.setBegin(42); // Works
console.log(lr.begin); // 42
```

Or as an interface (which the above would be able to implement, if you changed the name):

```
interface LineRange {
    readonly begin: number;
    setBegin(begin: number): void;
    readonly end: number;
    setEnd(end: number): void;
}
```

[Live example of the two together on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDKggJTiA5igbwChlTkoI4ATAexABsBPZAIwl1AC5kQBXAWzZQA3CTIBnCGABC7UAAo2HENz6DoASm4A3GsCqiy5SrQbMIIKqoFDDEqQFFL8i1Z43NOvQaIBfIkQI9HDi4mgY2HgQAMLBocjA-AAO9BD8FmBh6CBYOPjIxEYIdOJgULwIYDRQ8mJGpElQwNpwkMgA+kpc7upQADR19Y3NrSjtrta9gxoFg-5G+GCsciDyWj1Cs-VkFGC8UCDIYAAWwOIAdJ0rdqTz9jIriiuTQuu6+lvbR6cXV8rIAF5lsobsg7qRFshXGsXtBPttdvtDiczpdXKDwchJGAnFQXJZYVA3t54fUUb9XICoZYMX4AsUQKVkPQoAgqTkAO7hHKRfCxELieQABj6yCFGlEDPENFS53oNFw8hZCHOXRAEqIAHpNczWaqVlSACwAJmEyAAPACgQB1Gi8ehUZbIHBQqBQapEZXnbGyZTyE0S5Da5C2qAAa3EgRKMogcoVSr1aolQA)

---

Side note:

> I would not like to introduce a getBegin() function just for reading a simple member

I should note that technically, using an accessor property does introduce a function. But it doesn't make you use function call syntax when accessing the property, the function call is implicit.

You *can* avoid that, but only if you somewhat hide the `class` and only use the interface type:

```
interface LineRange {
    readonly begin: number;
    setBegin(begin: number): void;
    readonly end: number;
    setEnd(end: number): void;
}

class LineRangeClass implements LineRange {
    constructor(
        public begin: number,
        public end: number
    ) {
    }
    setBegin(begin: number): void {
        this.begin = begin;
    }
    setEnd(end: number): void {
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Usage, note that `lrc` is explicitly declared as `LineRange`, not `LineRangeClass` (obviously that name is a placeholder):

```
const lrc: LineRange = new LineRangeClass(0, 0);
console.log(lrc.begin);
// lrc.begin = 42; <== Would be an error
lrc.setBegin(42); // Works
console.log(lrc.begin);
```

But note that this would allow the assignment to `begin`, because I haven't supplied a type for `lrc` and so it's inferred to be `LineRangeClass`, which allows setting `begin`:

```
const lrc = new LineRangeClass(0, 0);
console.log(lrc.begin);
lrc.begin = 42; // <== NOT an error, because `lrc` is `LineRangeClass`
lrc.setBegin(42); // Works
console.log(lrc.begin);
```

Comment: I think the setters won't work if the properties are `readonly`. They need to be `private` in the class that implements the interface.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis - Try it. :-) I've added a playground link that works. We never actually try to assign to the readonly properties.

Comment: OK, just saw your demo.